# Center block in div with absolute position

Tags: css

I have a div with 2 blocks:

- One with informations
- Another absolute on the bottom (with variant height)

Problem: I would like to center image on the middle of the div, excluding absolute block.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nURsS.png)
[image]

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcZL2.png)
[image]

My actual code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ph4kfuy9/5/

```css
.block {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: 20px 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.absolute {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text">
    <p>My text</p>
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <p>Another text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="absolute">
    My absolute block
    <p>
      Quam ob rem cave Catoni anteponas ne istum quidem ipsum, quem Apollo, ut ais, sapientissimum iudicavit; huius enim facta, illius dicta laudantur. De me autem, ut iam cum utroque vestrum loquar, sic habetote.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank

Comment: You should be specifying what you have tried so far.

Comment: am I the only one to notice that both pictures are the same?

Comment: I can't really see any difference... Please describe what you want (annotations on image??)

Comment: The block with price is centered vertically

Comment: I just want to center vertically my text block in my grey div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use flex for this

```css
.block {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: 20px 50px;
  
  display:flex;             /* make this flex */
  flex-direction:column;    /* line up chld elements in a column */
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  flex-grow:1;              /* make this take up remaining space that footer doesn't */
  display:flex;             /* make this flex */
  flex-direction:column;    /* line up chld elements in a column */
  justify-content:center;   /* vertical centre */
  align-items:center;       /* horizontal centre */
}

.footer {                 /* no need to be absolute */
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text">
    <p>My text</p>
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <p>Another text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    My footer block
    <p>
      Quam ob rem cave Catoni anteponas ne istum quidem ipsum, quem Apollo, ut ais, sapientissimum iudicavit; huius enim facta, illius dicta laudantur. De me autem, ut iam cum utroque vestrum loquar, sic habetote.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have constraint, the footer block must be absolute, that is the problem

Comment: why must it be?  All you are doing is placing it at the bottom with your absolute, if you have it absolute, you may end up with your footer overlapping your main content, this way, your footer will always be at the bottom and never overlap any content.  Absolute positioning should only be used as a last resort or when you want to place things on top of other things (like modals, popups, etc)

Comment: Because it must be always on bottom, the div has variant height

Comment: Read my comment above and the comments in the code, try changing the height of the div and see what happens

Comment: Thank that's what I needed !